# Under which assumptions does Leibniz integral rule hold for measureable subsets?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, leibniz-integral-rule

Suppose $f$ is some measurable function. The Lebesgue version of the Leibniz integral rule is, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\Omega}f(x,y)dy=\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)dy.$$ for $x\in X\subset \mathbb{R}$, $y\in\Omega$, and $f$ is a function from $X\times \Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This statement only holds under some assumptions, namely

1. $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (as a function of $y$) for each $x$.
2. $f$ is differentiable (with respect to $x$) for almost all $y$.
3. There is an integrable function that dominates $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)|$ for all $x$ and almost all $y$.

(If I got something wrong here, please correct it)

**My Question:** Suppose we have an $f$ s.t. the above assumptions hold and let $S\subset \Omega$. Under which assumptions does  $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{S}f(x,y)dy=\int_{S}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)dy$$ hold?

I am interested in this question because a similar term turned up in a maximum likelihood estimation problem I am trying to solve. There, $S$ is a subset of the underlying Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Apply the rule to $f \cdot \chi_S$, where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function of $S$.

Comment: +1 A very useful hint. So it depends on the Lebesque measure of $S$, if I am not mistaken

Comment: @mto_19 On the measurability of $S$ to be precise, yes.